# Which Twitter API should I use to extract large amounts of tweets for NLP research?

Tags: api, twitter, nlp

I'd like to extract as many tweets containing a given keyword (typically a company name) as possible.

I've been using the Twitter Search API, but it's limited to "recent tweets". So for a relatively rare keyword, I can get no more than 500 tweets.

Twitter say that you shouldn't use the Search API for research. So, which API should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter doesn't provide free access to historical data. [Datasift](http://datasift.com/) and [Gnip](http://gnip.com/) are both selling access to the Twitter's firehose.

Answer (score 4):

To obtain lots of tweets with certain keywords, use the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api) with [Statuses/Filter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods).

First, create a file (e.g. "tracking.txt") with terms to [track](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods#track), with keywords which are comma separated.  This can include hash tags. For example, I used the following to obtain tweets with a link and certain hashtags.

```
track=http #baby,http #family,http #children, ...
```

Then, use curl to redirect the stream to a file.  Make sure to use your twitter id and password.

```
curl -d @tracking.txt https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json -uAnyTwitterUser:Password > stream.json
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid this API will just push me "new" tweets, not past tweets, am I right ? Since my keyword is rare, I need to get past tweets as well.

Comment: @Blacksad you're right. It might still be worth a try though, since given a large enough firehose, you may find enough data.

Comment: I tried, and I'm getting 1 or 2 tweets per hour for the given keyword I need. I'm not patient enough :)